# Python Getting id based on certain computed variables

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, import-from-excel

I have a Excel Sheet like this

```
      var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7
 Deg1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
 Deg2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 Deg3   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
 Deg4   1   1   0   0   1   >1  0   0
 Deg5   1   1   1   0   1   >1  0   0
 Deg6   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1
 Deg7   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1
```

I need to convert it into Python Data type as map or some thing which will help me to find the Deg's based on the variables

I have computed variables (var1, var2 .... ) and based on the variables value , I need to get the Deg1 or Deg2 or ....

How can this be achieved:

1. Converting Excel data to Python map or something
2. From the computed variables, how to get the degrees

Please help me

Comment: I think you want to look at the xlrd module, which will read Excel spdshts into python -- https://blogs.harvard.edu/rprasad/2014/06/16/reading-excel-with-python-xlrd/

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing that post but once it is converted how can i select the Deg's based on var's

Comment: The first comment is a good approach. I like to convert the excel file to a csv, and then use the csv.DictReader class (part of the standard python library) to read the data.

Any data that you read in (either using the first method suggested or my method) will initially be a string, so you have to convert it accordingly for your needs.

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for the idea.. but how to represent variables values >1 . Also the variables values i will compute and depending on the variable values i need to get the deg

Comment: For ex: if var1=1, var2=1, var3=1, var4=0, var5=4, var6 =1, var7=0                            Ans should be Deg5                                                                                                how to achieve this